# How to Respond to CP2000?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

I got a CP2000 from the IRS for 2016.  It concerns three retirement account transactions.

1. A direct rollover from an existing IRA to a Solo 401K (a qualified plan;
   1099-R Code G in box 7)
2. In 2016, I started to do a backdoor
   Roth and realized that I could not, so I had the funds returned. 
   These also triggered a 1099-R, and I think the code was "81" or "82"
   (I don't have it in front of me).
3. As #2, but for my wife.

It's not clear to me why the IRS thinks these would be taxable events.  For #1, the code in Box 7 seems to answer any question they would have about the transaction.  How do I further "prove" that this was a roll into a qualified plan?

For #2 and #3, I contributed post-tax dollars and had them returned.  If the contributions and returned funds were pre-tax dollars, wouldn't I have had to claim a deduction for that contribution?  Even if I had completed the backdoor Roth, it would have been with post-tax funds.

What will the IRS see as sufficient evidence as a response to incorrectly calling these distributions taxable?

Comment: Please edit Item 1.  Did you roll over from an IRA to a Solo 401(k) and _then_ to a different qualified plan (which suggests that the Solo 401k is not a qualified plan) or is the qualified plan the Solo 401(k) itself, i.e. there was only one rollover?